# Google Play Game Services - Is it possible to browse leaderboard and achevements via web?

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is it possible to browse Google Play Services Leaderboards and Achievements via web page (G+ or something)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible using their API. However, Google+ Sign-In is required. https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/index